# JAVA - How to store and read an RSA public key from an sqlite db

Tags: java, security, rsa

i have to store a public key and a private one into a sqlite database.
Actually i write the pubKey.getEncoded() into the database, and to recreate the pubkey i use the following code:

> ```
>     ResultSet result = stat.executeQuery("select publickey from cert where id='1'");
>     KeyFactory rsaKeyFac =  KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
>     X509EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(result.getBytes(1));
>     RSAPublicKey pubKey;
>     pubKey = (RSAPublicKey) rsaKeyFac.generatePublic(keySpec);
> ```

but it gives me the following error

> Exception in thread "main" java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.security.InvalidKeyException: IOException: Detect premature EOF

at this point :

> pubKey = (RSAPublicKey) rsaKeyFac.generatePublic(keySpec);

Anyone can help me?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

If you look here: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html you will see how to properly retrieve from a DB. That is assuming you have a type of char(n) for your DB column.

```
ResultSet result = stat.executeQuery("select publickey from cert where id='1'");
while(result.next())
{
   KeyFactory rsaKeyFac =  KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
   X509EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(result.getString(1));
   RSAPublicKey pubKey;
   pubKey = (RSAPublicKey) rsaKeyFac.generatePublic(keySpec);
}
```

If the type is a BLOB or CLOB then you need to use a different mechanism.
http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/jdbc/blob.html

Comment: It should be a BLOB. The getEncoded() encoding that is used produces bytes than can and will span the entire range from 0x00 to 0xff, and cannot be stored as character or string data.

Comment: Romain:
Your code is very similar to mine, and the result is similar too, it doesn't works. Same Exception.

Comment: GregS :
I've tried with the blob type, in the following way:

>result.next();
 KeyFactory rsaKeyFac=null;
 rsaKeyFac = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
 Blob pukey=result.getBlob(1);
 int leng=(int)pukey.length();
 X509EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(pukey.getBytes(1,leng));
 RSAPublicKey pubKey;
 pubKey = (RSAPublicKey) rsaKeyFac.generatePublic(keySpec);

i've got a new exception which say : 
java.sql.SQLException: not implemented by SQLite JDBC driver

so i think the blob exception is a sqlite limitation.

But the problem still persist, i'm not able to retrieve the pubkey!

Comment: @michele: If the pubkey was stored as a character object, then it may have been corrupted by the process. Character sets are limited but the public key bytes can take on any value. The public key *should* have been stored as a binary type, probably a BLOB.

Comment: In MySQL, there is a `VARBINARY` type that is used for storing binary data.

Comment: How can I get this work for an RSA Private Key and a Certificate?

Answer (score 0):

1. When you first get a ResultSet, the cursor points to the space *before* the first row of results. So you need to call next() on it before trying to retrieve the data.
2. You should make sure that the query actually succeeded.

Comment: you're right, but nothing has changed, the error is still present
the query correctly works